# How to display full name on memberpage after log in?

Tags: php, session

Who is code, and where is need to put, to display session fname and lname for logged user with session username.

This is my loginpage:

```
    <?php session_start();

//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    header('Location: memberpage.php');
    exit;

} else {
    $error[] = 'Погрешно корисничко име или лозинка, или вашиот акаунт не е активиран.';
}
```

And this is my memberpage:

```
<?php session_start(); 
require('includes/config.php'); 

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 

//define page title
$title = 'Профил';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

             <h2>Добредојдовте: <?php print_r($_SESSION)
;?></h2>
            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
            <p><a href='Update.php'>Update</a></p>
            <hr>

    </div>
 </div>


</div>
```

When use this code 
      "print_r($_SESSION)"
print only username, and member id. I'm tired using      "$_SESSION['Fname']=$_POST['Fname'];"

Comment: You declared $_SESSION['username'] = $username;. So in your memberpage, just use <?php echo $_SESSION('username'); ?> ?

Comment: @Chris G
Its ok. But i need to display first and last name of user. This not work in my case $_SESSION['Fname']=$_POST['Fname'];

Answer (score 0):

After user enter `username` and `password` you need select user from database and put first name and last name into `session`

In your case, you should edit `login` method. It should return row of current user. After that you need put it to `session`.

```
<?php session_start();

//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if($row = $user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];

    header('Location: memberpage.php');
    exit;

} else {
    $error[] = 'Погрешно корисничко име или лозинка, или вашиот акаунт не е активиран.';
}
```

Also always use `exit` after redirecting.

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php');exit; }
```

Comment: Still not work. When i print all session, give me this:
Array ( [loggedin] => 1 [username] => vale1 [memberID] => 2 [email] => [Fname] => )

Comment: I edit like you said.
if($row = $user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];  Not work.